# Haskell kinds. Beginner

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, data-kinds

What is the kind of `f`?

```
class C f where
    comp :: f b c -> f a b -> f a c
```

I have written: `(* -> *) -> * -> *`
Is this correct? `c` is a concrete type `*`. `a` is a type that takes a type and produces a type. And these both are the parameters for `f`? Is my argumentation correct?

What is kind of `T`?

```
data T f g = T (f String Int) (g Bool)
```

`f` has two concrete types as parameters (`String` and `Int`).  `g` has one parameter (`Bool`) These both are the parameters for `T`. So I have: `(*->*->*)->(*->*)->*`.
Is this correct? Thank you

Comment: In GHCi, `:info C` will tell you the kind of `f` and `:kind T` will tell you the kind of `T`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I suspect this is homework. Intended to be reasoned out with organic brain.

Comment: The names `f` and `comp` are an absolute giveaway.

Comment: FYI, the class `C` is just `Semigroupoid` from the `semigroupoids` package.

Answer (score 4):

GHCi can tell you the kinds of various things.  For example, if you put:

```
data T f g = T (f String Int) (g Bool)
```

in a file `Kinds.hs`, you can load it into GHCi and ask for the kind of `T`:

```
> :l Kinds.hs
> :k T
T :: (* -> * -> *) -> (* -> *) -> *
>
```

so it looks like GHCi agrees with your solution.

For your first question, you can't ask GHCi to tell you the kind of `f` directly, but since `f` is a parameter to the typeclass `C`, you can ask for the kind of `C`:

```
> :k C
C :: (* -> * -> *) -> Constraint
>
```

meaning that `C` takes a type of kind `* -> * -> *` to produce a constraint.  So, GHCi disagrees with you and thinks that `f` is of kind `* -> * -> *`.

Looking at the type signature for:

```
comp :: f b c -> f a b -> f a c
```

note that you couldn't have `f` of kind `(* -> *) -> * -> *` because `f b c` would imply that `b` was of kind `* -> *` while `f a b` would imply that `b` of of kind `*`, and it can't be both.

It turns out that the most general possible kind would be:

```
f :: k -> k -> *
```

where the first two arguments are forced to have the same kind `k` because `b` is used in both positions (in `f a b` and `f b c` respectively), and the final result is forced to have kind `*` because `f b c`, `f a b`, and `f a c` all need to be concrete types in order for the type signature of `comp` to make sense.

However, Haskell98 (no extensions) doesn't infer the most general possible kind, so it chooses `k` to be `*`, giving the kind signature `* -> * -> *`.  It turns out that if you enable a certain extension (`PolyKinds`), then the kind signature will be `k -> k -> *` instead.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, I don't see why you have decided that `a` has kind `* -> *`. From what is written, `a` is just a `*`, nothing more. Therefore, the kind of `f` is `* -> * -> *`.

For the second question, you are correct.